# New database structure is needed. Where to start?

Tags: mysql, database-design, bigdata, database-performance, olap

We currently have a product database in MySQL that has begun to cause some performance issues. There are at the given time about 500.000 products in the database, which is also getting continuely updated.

We obviously need to rethink our current database structure, but I have only very limited knowledge of this.

I was recomended to try getting an OLAP solution build, to see if this could help us out. What should we do - and where should we start?

Can anyone give us concrete examples of a good and very performance-friendly database structure?

Comment: I think 500K records is not big deal for mysql db if properly indexed done.

Comment: We are using LIKE multiple times in most searches - and we have a good indexing. However when we count every product available in our navigation and navigational filters, it starts to take time to fetch

Comment: You should use SOLR indexing for searching purpose. refer : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html#

Comment: I ahven't heard of Solr before. I will definatly look into it

Comment: Without looking at your database and usage scenario it's hard to say what the ideal solution would be. Obviously step 1, would be to identify and quantify the performance issues. You mention that generating the navigation is an issue, the obvious first steps are indexing and sql query tuning, a more drastic (but one which may give great performance) is some form of caching (maybe the counts that you are generating can be pre-computed on each product insertion/removal from a category).

Comment: Yes this has been a thought. However, counting products in a category is not much of an effort, but when also taking into consideration all the filters like brands, genders, colors etc. then there should be done a lot of caching all the time to secure accurate results all over the website. Also if it is a search query, then caching will not matter much, since it is a completely new set of results

Comment: There is no silver bullet. You simply won't be able to solve your problems without first understanding them. Unfortunately for you, database performance is a pretty big topic, but if you decide to take that journey, reading [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) would be a very good first step.